# Best way to trigger an archive functionality and move large (100GB+) files

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am looking for an advice on the best way to implement an archive functionality within GCP.
Basically, I want to archive files which consist of moving files from one bucket to another.

I have created a cloud function (python code) to trigger the file move functionality but I am running into timeout issues where the cloud function takes a lot of time to move the file (file sizes can be more than 100GB+).

This is the core of my code where I 'move' the object from one bucket to another:

```
if status == "DONE":
        #Archive CSV file
        try:
            source_blob = pub_bucket.blob(message['data']['filename'])
            new_blob = pub_bucket.copy_blob(
                source_blob, pri_bucket, folder_name+message['data']['filename'])
        except Exception as e: 
            print("Something went wrong when moving the file " + message['data']['filename'] + " to the private bucket: {}".format(e))
```

One important note, prior to archiving I do some file processing so I know the state of when the archive function can be triggered. So my question is more about what's the best way/architecture to trigger this archive functionality?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: may i know whats the purpose of acrchiving files after you done file processing.?

Comment: Hi @Cheti, the purpose is to move files out of the main bucket (which is public) to a private bucket. Thanks!

Comment: and when your triggering cloud function, is that afer you processd file or how your triggering or on what condition?

Comment: Cheti, I have one cloud function to process the data/file and within this function I consume pubsub which will trigger this archive function. So basically pubsub triggers the archive function to answer your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions have a default request timeout of 1 minute but you can further extend it to 9 minutes. If your job takes longer than that, then I suggest creating transfer jobs programmatically using [Transfer Service API](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview):

Transfer Service API returns a response immediately so you can use it on your function and not having to wait for the job to finish. In addition, you can schedule each transfer job and see its current status in the console.

To get started:

1. Enable [Storage Transfer API](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-client#enable).
2. Generate your Storage Transfer service account by trying the API in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/googleServiceAccounts/get).
3. On IAM, add the service account and give it `Storage Admin` and `Storage Transfer Admin` role.
4. Create a Python app and follow this sample code from [create data transfer docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-program#cloud-to-cloud):

```
import argparse
import datetime
import json

import googleapiclient.discovery


def main(description, project_id, start_date, start_time, source_bucket,
         sink_bucket):
    """Create a daily transfer from Standard to Nearline Storage class."""
    storagetransfer = googleapiclient.discovery.build('storagetransfer', 'v1')

    # Edit this template with desired parameters.
    transfer_job = {
        'description': description,
        'status': 'ENABLED',
        'projectId': project_id,
        'schedule': {
            'scheduleStartDate': {
                'day': start_date.day,
                'month': start_date.month,
                'year': start_date.year
            },
            'startTimeOfDay': {
                'hours': start_time.hour,
                'minutes': start_time.minute,
                'seconds': start_time.second
            }
        },
        'transferSpec': {
            'gcsDataSource': {
                'bucketName': source_bucket
            },
            'gcsDataSink': {
                'bucketName': sink_bucket
            },
            'objectConditions': {
                'minTimeElapsedSinceLastModification': '2592000s'  # 30 days
            },
            'transferOptions': {
                'deleteObjectsFromSourceAfterTransfer': 'true'
            }
        }
    }

    result = storagetransfer.transferJobs().create(body=transfer_job).execute()
    print('Returned transferJob: {}'.format(
        json.dumps(result, indent=4)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('description', help='Transfer description.')
    parser.add_argument('project_id', help='Your Google Cloud project ID.')
    parser.add_argument('start_date', help='Date YYYY/MM/DD.')
    parser.add_argument('start_time', help='UTC Time (24hr) HH:MM:SS.')
    parser.add_argument('source_bucket', help='Standard GCS bucket name.')
    parser.add_argument('sink_bucket', help='Nearline GCS bucket name.')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(args.start_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
    start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(args.start_time, '%H:%M:%S')

    main(
        args.description,
        args.project_id,
        start_date,
        start_time,
        args.source_bucket,
        args.sink_bucket)
```

5. Add the following dependencies:

```
google-api-python-client==2.7.0
google-auth==1.31.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
```

6. Test run it by following the arguments:

```
python py.py DESCRIPTION PROJECT_ID START_DATE START_TIME SOURCE_BUCKET SINK_BUCKET
```

ex:

```
python py.py test-description myproj 2021/06/29 00:00:00 mysource mydest
```

Additional notes:

- Configuring the transfer programmatically **requires time to be in UTC**. The sample will re-run the job daily. To make sure the transfer only runs one time, `scheduleEndDate` and `scheduleStartDate` must be the same and in the future relative to UTC.
- The sample job uses a Nearline storage as destination bucket. You can use other storage classes if you want.
- For one time transfers to run immediately, do not specify `startTimeOfDay`.
- To make finer adjustments to your code, refer to [`TransferJob`](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/transferJobs#Schedule).